# not found class $has_many through phpactiverecord

Tags: php, relationship, phpactiverecord

I have a many to many relationship between `Profesional` and `Plan` so I wrote the following code:

Profesional.php

```
class Profesional extends BaseModel {

    static $table_name = 'profesionales';
    static $primary_key = 'idprofesional';

    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            '_planes',
            'class_name' => 'Plan',
            'through' => '_profplanes'
        ),      
        array(
            '_profplanes',
            'class_name' => 'ProfPlan',
            'foreign_key' => 'profesional'
        )
    );
}
```

profplan.php

```
class ProfPlan extends BaseModel{

    static $table_name = 'profplanes';
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array(
            '_plan',
            'class_name' => 'Plan',
            'foreign_key' => 'plan'
        ),
        array(
            '_profesional',
            'class_name' => 'Profesional',
            'foreign_key' => 'profesional'
        )
    );

}
```

plan.php

```
class Plan extends BaseModel {

    static $table_name = 'planes';
    static $primary_key = 'idplan';
    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            '_profplanes',
            'class_name' => 'ProfPlan',
            'foreign_key' => 'plan'
        )
    );
}
```

But I get `Class Profplane does not exist`. Where is the error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your class is `Profplan`, not `Profplane`

Comment: @RoyalBg I know that. There is no part where I explicit `ProfPlane`. Why PHPActiveRecord throw this error?

Comment: Check the stacktrace and where the error is actually thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the class / table spellings! it'll be easy to fix early in your code and becomes a maintenance nightmare later on =P! "Plan->Plans' 'Profesional=>Professional', "Professionales->"Professionals".

Honestly the through relationship code in phpactiverecord is annoying, fickle, and really needs to be looked at in general.

You should show how you're actually calling the code, but I'm going to assume you're doing

```
Professional::find(1)
$professional->_plans, //Error is thrown here
```

You need to set up your code so that `ProfPlan->_plans`(or `_planes` in your case), is definded, and not just `ProfPlan->_plan`.  Phpactiverecord needs to explicitly know the relationship it's going to go through.  Let me know if you need a more clear explanation.